# tkinter checkbutton values print

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I create checkbutton which create list of crops. I want to print the crop the user select but its always print me the same crop (and crop that I didnt select) anyone know what worng?

```
def set_check(event):
    global b
    var_lst=[]



    for widget in radios:
        widget.destroy()
    if cb_elemnt.get(): # get the crops according to element selection
        if cb_elemnt.get() != "N":
            crop_values = 
pd.unique(df.loc[df["elemnt"].eq(cb_elemnt.get()),"crop"])
        else:
            crop_values = pd.unique (df_nir.loc[df_nir["elemnt"].eq 
(cb_elemnt.get ()), "crop"])


    for num, t in enumerate(crop_values, 1): # create and add the crops to check button with number start from
        chkValue =IntVar ()
        checkbox_variable = IntVar ()
    # I need seperate var for each crop
        b = Checkbutton (top, text=t, variable=checkbox_variable, font=("Segoe UI Light", 10))
        checkbox_variables.append (checkbox_variable)
        b.grid (row=num, column=2, sticky='W', padx=40)
        radios.append (b)

def regression():
#PLSR
if cb_elemnt.get () != "N":
    if var1.get():
        element_u= cb_elemnt.get () #The element that the user selected
        print(element_u)
        for checkbox in checkbox_variables:  
            if checkbox.get ()==1:
                print(b.cget("text"))
```

Comment: You can set  `onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0` for `Checkbutton`

Comment: its defult no? I am  trying to print the text of the button that mark by the user by its always print the same one no matter what I selected

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at what you are doing:

You run a loop that keeps re-assigning `b` to be a different `Checkbutton`. `b` will always be the very last `Checkbutton` you create.

```
for num, t in enumerate(crop_values, 1):
    b = Checkbutton (top, text=t, variable=checkbox_variable, font=("Segoe UI Light", 10))
```

Later on you treat `b` as if it can magically be any `Checkbutton` you need at any given time.

```
for checkbox in checkbox_variables:  
    if checkbox.get ()==1:
        print(b.cget("text"))
```

Solution:

Create a `list` of `Checkbutton` that have indexes that directly correlate to your `checkbox_variables` `list`.

Example:

```
for row, text in enumerate(crop_values, 1): 
    checkbox_variables.append(IntVar())
    checkboxes.append(Checkbutton(top, text=text, variable=checkbox_variables[-1], font=("Segoe UI Light", 10)))
    checkboxes[-1].grid(row=row, column=2, sticky='W', padx=40)

#and ...

for checkbox, var in zip(checkboxes, checkbox_variables):
    if var.get():
        print(checkbox['text'])
```

Edit:
Upon reading your code further you were already appending `Checkbutton` to `?radios?` (lol), but failed to use `radios` to get the corresponding `Checkbutton` in the next loop. As an aside: A `Radiobutton` and a `Checkbutton` are not the same thing. `Checkbutton` is a solitary `boolean` value. `Radiobutton` is a group of `boolean` values where one has to be `True` and only one can be `True`. You should consider your variable names more accurately. What if you started using `Radiobutton`, as well? What would you call the `list` that you need to stick those in?